# Is there any software application for Ubuntu like RAMDisk by Dataram?

Tags: software-recommendation, ram, disk-image, tmpfs

Currently I create a ramdisk in Windows7 by using [this RamDisk software by DataRam](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) that has the ability to save RamDisk virtual disk image on shutdown and restore on Windows startup and sync data to hard disk automatically at specified time intervals.

I am looking for an application with similar functionality in Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

It is built into Ubuntu. For a RAM disk, do this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=256M tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk/
```

This will give you a 256M RAM disk mounted at /mnt/ramdisk.

Comment: *(...) has the ability to save RamDisk virtual disk image on shutdown and restore on windows startup and sync data to hard disk automatically on specified time interval (...)*

Comment: @BrunoPereira That requirement was added after my answer...

Comment: Mhhh, thats the whole point of the product, so its not a requirement its the whole base of it, no? :)

Comment: @Jos Anyhow, thanks for the answer, no issues. If you know how to save data to disk periodically and save & auto mount data on shutdown, startup. Please update your answer.

Comment: @Sampath For a periodical save, have cron execute an `rsync` command from the ramdisk to somewhere else. Write init.d scripts or Upstart scripts to backup (at shutdown) and restore (at startup) the data, again using a single `rsync` command. I think that covers the whole functionality of the product.